# Why are the nav bar links in the wrong order?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've programmed my nav bar but the links are in the wrong order so why is it like this? and how can I fix it? It is in the right order for the mobile version, it just the desktop version which is in the wrong order. Here is my html code:

```
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <img src='images/ared logo.jpeg ' width="120" height="40">
    <a href="">Home</a>
    <a href="">About us</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Services
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Sports</a>
          <a href="#">Events</a>
          <a href="#">Social media</a>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <a href="">Medical</a>
      <a href="" >Testmonies</a>
      <a href="" >Case study</a>
      <a href="" >Blog & news</a>
    <a href="" >Contact us</a>
   
   
   

  

  

    <img src='images/login icon.png ' width="30" height="30" style="text-align: right; 
    float:right;padding-top:10px" >

  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776; 
  </a>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
.topnav {
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #fffcf6;
}

.topnav a {
float: right;
display: block;
color: #000;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 12pt;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.active {
background-color: #ecad5d;
color: #000;
}

.topnav .icon {
display: none;
}

.dropdown {
float: right;
overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
font-size: 12pt;
border: none;
outline: none;
color: #000;
padding: 14px 16px;
background-color: inherit;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
margin: 0;

}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #fffcf6;
min-width: 100px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
float: none;
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: #ecad5d;
color: #000;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
background-color: #ecad5d;
color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

.topnav a:not(:first-child),
.dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
}

.topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
}

.topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.topnav.responsive .dropdown {
    float: none;
}

.topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
    position: relative;
}

.topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}
}
```

Here is a picture of what it looks like: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiYnO.png)

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: you are using bootstrap library?

Comment: .topnav a {float: right;} because of this css you are using this to float elements right

Comment: I want them to be on the right but they are in reverse order for some reason

Comment: And what have you tried to check why this happens?

Comment: you are putting float right for each anchor link, that's why

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/ this might help you

Comment: You should consider using flex instead. It's much simpler.

Answer (score 4):

A solution is to float the whole div element instead of <a elements. Or in another words:

```
.topnav {
   float: right;
 }
```

and remove the `float` in the `.topnav a`

If you want your img to float on the left side, you can separate the a links with an another div element:

```
<div class="topnav">
  <img ...>
<div class="topnav-right>
   <a href=...>
</div>
</div>
```

In that way `topnav-right` should have the `float: right;`

Best Regards,
ykostov

Answer (score 0):

If you use `display:flex` it will work. Atleast it will resolve the problem that you asked.

```
    .topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fffcf6;
      display:flex;
    }
```

[image: image of the result]

Comment: You haven't used flex in the code but it produce result. You haven't specified the method to do it  

Comment: yes it works but I want the links to be on the right hand side

Comment: I didn't understand your question, Are you talking about `a` , `img` tags?

Comment: yes I want the a tags and img to be on the right hand side and the logo to be on the left

Comment: Do you mean this ??    [image of the result ](https://i.imgur.com/fCkQDf0.png)

Comment: No I want the picture to be at the other end next to contact us

Comment: @cherlloydfan1 please share picture, Atleast draw buttons roughly so that I can understand it easily